# Android - get data from json

Tags: android, json

I have a api call that returns this json object:

```
{
    "elenco": [
        "folder 1",
        "folder 2",
        "folder 3"
    ],
    "codice": "123456789"
}
```

and this is my piece of code that get the result:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

        // Close progress dialog
        Dialog.dismiss();

        JSONObject jobj = null;
        String codice_utente = null;
        JSONArray elenco_cartelle = null;

        try {

            jobj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(result));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Provo a recuperare i campi json
        try {

            codice_utente = jobj.getString("codice");
            elenco_cartelle = jobj.getJSONArray("elenco");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //This should fetch the elenco array
        for (int i = 0; i < elenco_cartelle.length(); i++) {  

            JSONObject childJSONObject = null;

            try {

                childJSONObject = elenco_cartelle.getJSONObject(i);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

           //Can't use getString here...

        }



    }
```

How can I fetch the `elenco` part? I do not have a key to use, so how can I add every row in an ArrayList?
I tried to use a for but I have no idea about how to get the rows

Comment: `//Can't use getString here...` why this comment?

Comment: Because I tougth I should git to that method the name as I did for `codice`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSONArray.getString()` http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#getString(int)

```
for (int i = 0; i < elenco_cartelle.length(); i++) {  

            String content = null;

            try {

                content = elenco_cartelle.getString(i);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       //Can't use getString here...

    }
```

You now have your content on `content`

Comment: Thanks Pedro, the solution was much more simple than I thought! I will accept asap